# FTP для прошивки комутатора

Tags: ftp, sftp, коммутатор

Имею пустую железку SNR S2982G-24T
без прошивки в режиме boot, проблема в том что для прошивки выходит в сеть без gateway
поднял на локальной машине ftp c 10.90.90.1

подключаюсь по minicom начинаю прошивку

```
[Boot]: ping 10.90.90.1                                                                            
Using rtl8380#0 device
host 10.90.90.1 is alive
[Boot]: load /file:/Desktop/SNR-S2982G-24T(-POE)_7.0.3.5(R0241.0374)/SNR-S2982G-24T_7.2.41_boot.rom
Using rtl8380#0 device
TFTP from server 0.0.0.0; our IP address is 10.90.90.4
Filename '/Desktop/SNR-S2982G-24T(-POE)_7.0.3.5(R0241.0374)/SNR-S2982G-24T_7.2.41_boot.rom'.
Load address: 0x81000000
Loading: T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T 
Retry count exceeded; starting again
Using rtl8380#0 device
TFTP from server 0.0.0.0; our IP address is 10.90.90.4
Filename '/Desktop/SNR-S2982G-24T(-POE)_7.0.3.5(R0241.0374)/SNR-S2982G-24T_7.2.41_boot.rom'.
Load address: 0x81000000
Loading: T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T 
Abort
```

явно неправильно настроил ftp, дефолтные настройки не пускают без пользователя.

подрубленные настройки /etc/vsftpd.conf

```
listen=YES
background=YES
listen_address=10.90.90.1
listen_ipv6=NO
anonymous_enable=YES
anon_root=/home/shulg/Desktop
local_enable=YES
local_umask=022
anon_upload_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=NO
```

Как правильно настроить ftp для допуска?
не часто работал с ftp и линуксом, настроил вот основное и деталей многих не знаю.

Comment: в параметрах 
anonymous_enable=YES
anon_root=/home/shulg/Desktop

что то еще нужно указать?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать TFTP сервер, например, tftpd-hpa. Vsftpd не подойдет - там другой ftp.

Comment: из доступных tftp options указаны TFTP_OPTIONS="--ipv4 --secure --create --umask 027 --permissive"
где create разрешает серверу создавать новые файлы,
ipv4 предписывает ему ожидать подключений только на адресах IPv4,
umask предписывает сбрасывать бит записи для группы и все биты доступа для остальных пользователей,
permissive предписывает не проводить никаких проверок прав доступа к файлу сверх производимых операционной системой.

из этого не сильно понятно что оставить для успешного запроса с железки.

Comment: TFTP_USERNAME="tftp"
TFTP_DIRECTORY="/home/shulg/Desktop/SNR"
TFTP_ADDRESS="10.90.90.1"
TFTP_OPTIONS="--ipv4 --premissive"
****************************************************************
дериктория возможно в области доступа только для локальных пользователей 
опции указал вроде логичные

Comment: @IlyaShulgin буду запускать завтра-послезавтра для прошивки тплинка. напишу пошагово.

Answer (score 0):

По итогу выяснилось что есть несколько путей закачать файл и выгрузить прошивку.
Вероятно на моём комутаторе сгорела память. Вот почему:
при подключении по ftp
в boot режиме без прошивки когда инструментарий комутатора ограничен, и необходимо загрузить в него прошивку использовали следующие функции
setconfig
ip железки самой
ip ftp сервера

load *полный путь до файла* в моем случае /var/tftp/boot.rom
происходила загрузка прогрессбар загружался выдавал done.

прописывая dir обнаруживалось что boot.rom не появлялся на комутаторе.

run nos.img
выдавал corrupted data

при load /var/tftp/nos.img
загружал файл по итогу выдавал done
но файл на комутаторе не менялся

далее пробовали через minicom функцией xmodem
на комутаторе
xmodem
сочитание клавиш Ctrl+a -> z
нажимаем S
выбираем xmodem
и выбираем файл для загрузки

в нашем случае после завершения загрузки получали сообщение о провале
файл на комутаторе не менялся.